# Can any one come up with a better solution for the below code for finding path from a source to a destination node in BST?

Tags: python, algorithm, binary-tree, binary-search-tree, time-complexity

```
class BST:

    def __init__(self, val=None):
        self.left = None
        self.right = None
        self.val = val

    def __str__(self):
        return "[%s, %s, %s]" % (self.left, str(self.val), self.right)

    def insert(self, val):
        if self.isEmpty():
            self.val = val
        elif val < self.val:
            if self.left is None:
                self.left = BST(val)
            else:
                self.left.insert(val)
        else:
            if self.right is None:
                self.right = BST(val)
            else:
                self.right.insert(val)

    def printpath(self,val,path):
        if self.val == val:
            return path
        if self.val > val:
            self.left.printpath(val,path)
        else:
            self.right.printpath(val,path)
        path.append(self.val)


a = BST(4)
a.insert(2)
a.insert(3)
a.insert(5)
a.insert(1)
a.insert(7)
a.insert(6)
a.insert(0)
print a

s = 0
d = 6
lpath = []
rpath = []
lpath.append(s)
a.printpath(s,lpath)
a.printpath(d,rpath)
rpath.reverse()
rpath.append(d)
print lpath,rpath
```

Comment: I could be wrong, but it looks like half your functions don't have anything to do with solving the problem at hand, could you remove them and only leave the applicable function(s)?

Comment: It is just a partial code.If there is a way to do this then please give the solution or atleast provide a link which might help.

Answer (score 0):

What you do is to find the find the path from the root node top both the source and target nodes and then concatenate both (in the right way, that is, with reversing one of the paths).

If the tree was balanced (which it most likely isn't going to be with your code), this is going to be O(log n) and that's hard to beat.

The only thing I would fix is that you path might be unnecessarily long. For example, take for the following tree:

```
    4
   /
  2
 / \
1   3
```

If you were searching for path from 1 to 3, your code would return 1, 2, 4, 4, 2, 3. This path could be actually shortened to just 1, 2, 3. To fix that, you could first compute both parts of the path and then look their ends. While the ends are the same, shorten both parts. In the end, don't forgot to include the last removed element (but only once).

If you want to make the code faster, you could create both parts of the path step by step and stop when they meet. But doing this would make your code more complicated (it would require using something like hash set, or, even better storing the depth in each node) for what is most likely not significant increase in performance.